# Calculate S3 object(folder) size in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Im storing all types of files on amazon S3. In amazon S3 bucket, All files store in different folders, I know there is no concept of folder in amazon s3. Objects are only identified by their keys. if i store any file with key like 'mydocs/personal/profile-pic.jpg' that mean two parents folders(personal folder inside mydocs folder) will be created there.

I want to calculate the size of any folder like 'mydocs' in java. I calculated bucket total size by using this code given below:

```
public long calculateBucketSize(String bucketName) {
long totalSize = 0;
    int totalItems = 0;
    ObjectListing objects = listObjects(bucketName);
    do {
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
            totalSize += objectSummary.getSize();
            totalItems++;
        }
        objects = listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
    } while (objects.isTruncated());
    System.out.println("Amazon S3 bucket: " + bucketName + " containing "
            + totalItems + " objects with a total size of " + totalSize
            + " bytes.");

    return totalSize;
}
```

This method will return the bucket total size. I want to calculate the size of any single folder.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try using objects=listObjects(bucketName/foldername) , as in try to just parse through folder objects and calculate total size.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to this with org.apache.hadoop lib

```
  def calculateSize(path: String)(implicit spark: SparkSession): Long = {
    val fsPath = new Path(path)
    val fs = fsPath.getFileSystem(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    fs.getContentSummary(fsPath).getLength
  }
```

This function can calculate size in s3, hdfs and local file system

Answer (score 1):

For Scala developers, here it is recursive function to execute a ***full scan and map*** of the contents of an AmazonS3 bucket using the official [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)

```scala
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.{S3ObjectSummary, ObjectListing, GetObjectRequest}
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.{collectionAsScalaIterable => asScala}

def map[T](s3: AmazonS3Client, bucket: String, prefix: String)(f: (S3ObjectSummary) => T) = {

  def scan(acc:List[T], listing:ObjectListing): List[T] = {
    val summaries = asScala[S3ObjectSummary](listing.getObjectSummaries())
    val mapped = (for (summary <- summaries) yield f(summary)).toList

    if (!listing.isTruncated) mapped.toList
    else scan(acc ::: mapped, s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing))
  }

  scan(List(), s3.listObjects(bucket, prefix))
}
```

To invoke the above curried `map()` function, simply pass the already constructed (and properly initialized) AmazonS3Client object (refer to the official [AWS SDK for Java API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html)), the bucket name and the prefix name in the first parameter list. Also pass the function `f()` you want to apply to map each object summary in the second parameter list.

For example

```scala
val tuple = map(s3, bucket, prefix)(s => (s.getKey, s.getOwner, s.getSize))
```

will return the full list of `(key, owner, size)` tuples in that bucket/prefix

or

```scala
map(s3, "bucket", "prefix")(s => s.getSize).sum
```

will return the total size of that bucket/prefix contents

You can combine `map()` with many other functions as you would normally approach by [Monads in Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29)

Answer (score 1):

For the Java AWS SDK V2, here is an example:

```java
  public Long getFolderSize(String bucket, String prefix) {
    ListObjectsV2Request request =
        ListObjectsV2Request.builder().bucket(bucket).prefix(prefix).build();
    ListObjectsV2Iterable list = s3Client.listObjectsV2Paginator(request);
    long totalSize = 0;
    long numberItems = 0;
    for (S3Object object : list.contents()) {
      totalSize += object.size();
      numberItems++;
    }
    logger.info(
        "The size of the folder {}, is {} bytes, number of items {}",
        bucket + prefix,
        totalSize,
        numberItems);
    return totalSize;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get size of folder at each level. Like if you have one root folder R-Folder and two sub folder  S1.1-Folder, S1.2-Folder and then S1.1-Folder has again three subfolder S1.1.1-Folder, S1.1.2-Folder, S1.1.3-Folder. Now you want the folder size of each folder

```
R-Folder (32MB)
|__S1.1-Folder (22MB)
|  |__S1.1.1-Folder (7MB)
|  |__S1.1.2-Folder (5MB)
|  |__S1.1.3-Folder (10MB)
|
|__S1.2-FOlder (10MB)
```

Am I correct ?

You have to keep list folder details with status isCompleted or not - and scan each folder recursively. and when internal folder completed successfully then you have to update the size at its corresponding parent and that parent will update the to there corresponding parent and this will continue each time till root.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you got my question but its not suitable solution as by doing so, if i have hundreds of files and folders, it will take hell of time to calculate the parent folder size. It will be recursive loop to calculate all child file/folders. I need solution like i posted code above to calculate whole bucket size, or Its better i store sizes of file and folders in database and calculate sum all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Stucked in the same problem, the simple solution is using :

```
 ObjectListing objects = listObjects(bucketName,prefix);
```

Where prefix is your folder name.

For more information see this links:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html

Comment: How to calculate disk usage? Loop through `getObjectSummaries()`, and count the total of every file?

Answer (score 0):

The below code gets all the files in a given prefix/key and returns the total size.

```
public Long listS3FolderSize(String bucket, String dirPrefix) {
    Long folderSizeInBytes = 0L;
    List<S3ObjectSummary> objectsListing = getObjectSummaryList(bucket, dirPrefix);
    for (S3ObjectSummary summary: objectsListing) {
        folderSizeInBytes += summary.getSize();
    }

    return folderSizeInBytes;
}
```